# explanation of BFS code (Java)

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, breadth-first-search

This is the code i found for BFS but i'm having trouble understanding the working. 
 Things like : 
    `int number_of_nodes = adjacency_matrix[source].length - 1;`
and why take `int[] visited = new int[number_of_nodes + 1];` ?

```
public void bfs(int adjacency_matrix[][], int source)
{
    int number_of_nodes = adjacency_matrix[source].length - 1;

    int[] visited = new int[number_of_nodes + 1];
    int i, element;

    visited[source] = 1;
    queue.add(source);

    while (!queue.isEmpty())
    {
        element = queue.poll();
        i = element;
        System.out.print(i + "\t");
        while (i <= number_of_nodes)
        {
            if (adjacency_matrix[element][i] == 1 && visited[i] == 0)
            {
                queue.add(i);
                visited[i] = 1;
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question seems to be a lack of understanding what `adjacency_matrix` is, and since this code doesn't explain that, why don't you go back to where you found this, and have another look?

Comment: I know what an adjacency matrix is. I just dont understand why the number of nodes is being counted in this way.

Comment: Are you asking "why the `- 1`"? If so, it's because whoever wrote the code decided to do it that way.

Comment: You *could* remove `- 1`, and the `+ 1` on the next line, and change `i <= number_of_nodes` to `i < number_of_nodes`, and it would function the same. --- But I would say that the code is *wrong*, since `i` should start at 0, not at `element`.

Answer (score 0):

BFS is a short form for Breadth-First-Search. Starting from a source vertex, the direct neighbours are processed first, followed by the direct neighbours of those and so on.

```
 while (!queue.isEmpty())
{
    element = queue.poll();
    i = element;
    System.out.print(i + "\t");
    while (i <= number_of_nodes)
    {
        if (adjacency_matrix[element][i] == 1 && visited[i] == 0)
        {
            queue.add(i);
            visited[i] = 1;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

The 4th line is not needed as you can simply print `element` directly. `i` should start at 0 as you are trying to iterate through the possible neighbours of the current vertex (represented by`element`).